# Cant pull or push dockerhub repo to or from my local machine - docker

Tags: django, docker, dockerhub

I have a local project I want to push to docker hub. I have an account with docker hub and i created a repository for testing docker out. My local file with my project is called docker-test and it is a django application. My docker hub project is also named docker-test. I am running the following commands and I am getting the following errors... Can anyone help me...

This is the push

```
docker push omaryap/docker-test
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/omaryap/docker-test]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: omaryap/docker-test
```

this is the pull

```
omars-mbp:docker-test omarjandali$ docker pull omaryap/docker-test
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for omaryap/docker-test:latest not found
```

This is the link to my docker hub repository:

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/omaryap/docker-test/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> docker push omaryap/docker-test
>   The push refers to a repository [docker.io/omaryap/docker-test]
>   An image does not exist locally with the tag: omaryap/docker-test

says that, there is no local image with that tag. So first you need to build the image and tag it locally, before pushing it to the hub.

And this error

> omars-mbp:docker-test omarjandali$ docker pull omaryap/docker-test
>   Using default tag: latest
>   Error response from daemon: manifest for omaryap/docker-test:latest not found

is saying that there is no image in that repository.

Please build the image. I recommend you to start with creating a docker file for your application and then building it locally.

You can follow this link for step by step process
https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-python-django-web-application